# How to query the properties of objects?

Tags: graphics, image, fonts

General question: How does one query the properties of objects in Mathematica. For example, if g is a `Graphics` object, how do I find out its size? Or how do I find out the font size of a `Text` object?

Particular purpose: I would like to use `Magnify` to view large images at the manageable 1280x720 resolution. So I need to know how large the image is so I know how much to resize it.

Comment: If the graphics object is saved in the variable `plt`, then do `Options[plt]`. Although there are hidden default settings.

Comment: To scale a `Graphics` object `g`, try `Show[g,ImageSize->Full]`. You can also try `Show[g,ImageSize->{1280,720}]`.

Comment: Henrik, this solution changes the relative size of MaTeX objects which is the original reason I had to use Magnify.